# how to solve this recurrence relation with the initial conditions given

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

**a<sub>0</sub> = 2  &  b<sub>0</sub> = -1**

**3*a<sub>n</sub> - 2*a<sub>n-1</sub> -b<sub>n-1</sub>= 0**

**3*b<sub>n</sub> - 2*b<sub>n-1</sub> -a<sub>n-1</sub>= 0**

please help me in Solving this recurrence relation for a<sub>n</sub> and b<sub>n</sub> with system of equations . i tried solve this with  distinct roots way but i was failed , i could just approach to this :

a<sub>n</sub> +  b<sub>n</sub> =  a<sub>n-1</sub> +  b<sub>n-1</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Add the two equations together, and you get

\begin{align}
& (3a_n-2a_{n-1}-b_{n-1})+(3b_n-2b_{n-1}-a_{n-1})=0 \\
\implies & (a_n+b_n)-(a_{n-1}+b_{n-1})=0
\end{align}

So if we define a new sequence $c_n :=a_n+b_n$, then we know that $c_n$ satisfies

$$c_n-c_{n-1}=0 \qquad \qquad c_0=a_0+b_0=1$$

From this, we see that $c_n = 1$ for all $n$. i.e. we have

$$a_n+b_n=c_n=1 \quad \forall n \in \Bbb N \\ \implies b_n =1-a_n \quad \forall n \in \Bbb N$$

Plugging this back in to the first equation, we have

$$3a_n-2a_{n-1}-\underbrace{b_{n-1}}_{=1-a_{n-1}}=0 \implies 3a_n-a_{n-1}=1$$

The general solution is

$$a_n = A\bigg(\frac 13\bigg)^n+\frac 12$$

for some constant $A$. Applying the initial condition $a_0=2$, we find that $A=\frac 32$. Hence, the solution is

$$a_n = \frac 12 \bigg(1+\bigg(\frac 13\bigg)^{n-1}\bigg) \qquad \qquad b_n = \frac 12 \bigg(1-\bigg(\frac 13\bigg)^{n-1}\bigg)$$